# Three.js textures not rendering on mobile and weird brightness issue

Tags: javascript, mobile, three.js

So I made a project using Three.js and everything works how I want it to on desktop browsers, tested using chrome, and firefox. When I try to open the project on any mobile browser, safari, chrome, or IE, some objects are not rendered these objects have normal maps and textures which appear fine on desktop but are not rendered at all on mobile. In addition objects appear to be overly bright on mobile and sometimes flicker going from behind one another to in front of one another.

One user suggested adding this.image = image; to the three.js file at line 18420 but this did not solve the issue. Here is a link to the project here http://pixelpusher.ninja/Ocean%20World/OceanWorld.html. You can inspect the page to view the source code. Has anyone ran into problems like this on mobile before? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so I figured out that the weird brightness issue and disappearing textures was due to using StandardMaterial and PhongMaterial. I am still not sure why these matierals cause such weird errors on mobile. I feel that mobile browsers are just not yet fully equipped to handle all the capabilities of WebGL.